# How can I redefine where (0,0) of a QGraphicsItem is?

Tags: c++, qt, coordinates, qgraphicsitem

I've a custom `QGraphicsItem` which draws nothing but is parent to other `QGraphicsItems` (like `QGraphicsRectItem` and so on). My top-level item has `(0,0)` somewhere "inside" the children Items. This is very inconvenient. I would like to shift the origin to the upper left corner of `childrenBoundingRect()`.

In the picture I've `(0,0)` of my top-level item somewhere inside of my children items (solid arrow). I would like to shift the origin to the dashed lines. How can I do that?

As result I expect that positioning of the top-level item will be more convenient.

[image]

Comment: Ensure you add the children with a relative position to the parent item greater than 0 on both the x and y axes. You can't "redefine" a point in the coordinate system.

Comment: Perhaps use a convenience function that returns the origin of an item's `childrenBoundingRect`?

Comment: Simple: move the children! Or translate the coordinate system to the top left of the `childrenBoundingRect` after the children have been added.

Answer (score 1):

Examples for overriding [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html) often show the [boundingRect()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) function originating from (0,0). Changing this will change the origin. So, for example, to change it to the centre, where width and height are variables stored internally in the class, you can do this: -

```
QRectF boundingRect() const
{
    return (-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According to this question, an item should only return it's own boundingRect because of redrawing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448321/should-qgraphicsitemboundingrect-include-child-bounding-rects
I will that that and see which way I go.

Comment: I'm not suggesting returning the bounding rect of another item, just the child items in this case.